# No target response variable in my testing data

Tags: classification, training

I have two datasets which are the training and testing set. The training data has a target variable, but the testing set does not. What should I do to fix the issue with the testing set?

Comment: Kaggle? Use some (random) part of the training data to test performance or do cross validation on the training set

Answer (score 2):

Usually, two datasets are given, one is training where you build and evaluate the model. The second is the held-out dataset.

Since you have a labeled training dataset and an unlabeled test dataset, I am assuming, you're appearing for a competition where labels for the test dataset have not been given to avoid learning from the test dataset.

You should use the labeled training dataset and split it into train tests or in k-folds in an 80:20 split. Train your model on 80% of the split and validated/test on 20% of the data.

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow-up question. Then how can I use the testing data to validate my predictions? Would that be impossible?

Comment: Can you give an example? @Neelesh Shukla

Comment: Use part of the training dataset itself to create test data set to validate your predictions.

Comment: Do you have a code example?

Answer (score 0):

If label is not given for testing dataset .You can split your train datset into 3 parts like train,valid and test split in ratio of 70:15:15 and you can work on it.You can use first train and validation to fit like model.fit(train,val) and after that you can evaluate your model performance with the help of test data like model.evaluate(test) which shows accuracy for your newly seen test data set...